# extracting part of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Which is the best way to extract part of a vector? If I have

```
std::vector<int> v1(9);

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    v1[i] = i + 1;
```

I need a code that put in

```
std::vector<int> v2(2);
```

the second and third element of v1. I have to do a cycle or there is a smartest way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this using the iterator form of `vector` constructor

```
 std::vector<int> v2(v1.begin() + 1,v1.begin() + 3);
```

If `v2` already exists use `assign`

```
v2.assign(v1.begin() + 1,v1.begin() + 3);
```

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds!

Comment: I know this, but my vector v2 is already existing... I can't use constructor, so?

Comment: @mathematician1975 it seems that your code doesn't work

Comment: @Wellen works fine on my machine

Comment: @mathematician1975 alright, it works if I write `v2.assign(v1.begin() + 1,v1.begin() + 3);` and not `+2`. However, do you think this is the smartest way or using `std::copy` is equivalent?

Comment: @Wellen - I apologise - i had a typo above. It needs to be +3.

Comment: @Wellen I am not certain about speed but if I were coding this myself with large subsets of vectors then I would likely actually use `memcpy` to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::copy(), Suppose if you want to insert 1st and 2nd element from v1 to the beginning of v2 then you can use following.

```
std::copy ( v1.begin()+1, ,v1.begin() + 3, v2.begin() );
```